# I can't apply a round border on table cells

Tags: html, html-table, border-radius

I'm building a very basic test website in HTML, and I'm learning how to put borders on table cells. I have a problem, I'm trying to round the borders in my table but I just get rounded cells (`td` and `th`), but not the table itself.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  border: 5px solid aqua;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 45px;
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 11px;
}

th {
  color: white;
  font-family: impact;
}

td {
  color: yellow;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<table align=c enter>
  <tr>
    <th>Choncho</th>
    <th>Klokin</th>
    <th>Fetuc</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>300</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>papas</td>
    <td>refrescos</td>
    <td>tingas</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I even tried doing the following to see if there were any changes:

```css
table {
  border-radius: 45px;
}

the, 
td {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  border: 5px solid aqua; 
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 11px;
}
```

But all the borders remain squares.

Comment: As a side note, it is not helpful to mix things into your title and description that has nothing to do with the issue. Your title asks about the border of an HTML List (`ul`, `ol`, and `menu`). In your question itself, you don't have a list at all. You talk about `ph` and `pd` when your actual question is about tables and `td` and `th`. That only confuses others and makes it harder to receive a helpful answer.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't realize of it, I was talking about tables, td and th values, I don't know why I put lists and ph and pd, sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

I think that has something to do with collapsing the border.

Try to remove this line

```css
border-collapse: collapse;
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  border: 5px solid aqua;
  /* border-collapse: collapse; *//* remove this line */
  border-radius: 45px;
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 11px;
}

th {
  color: white;
  font-family: impact;
}

td {
  color: yellow;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<table align=c enter>
  <tr>
    <th>Choncho</th>
    <th>Klokin</th>
    <th>Fetuc</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>300</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>papas</td>
    <td>refrescos</td>
    <td>tingas</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then use `padding` and `margin` to control the spacing if needed

Comment: this does not effect the border-radius or apply a round border-radius to the table.

Comment: He already uses `border-radius: 45px;` but it is not being considered due to the use of `border-collapse: collapse;`

Comment: Thanks mate, I removed the border-collapse line and it worked, I think it didn't work because while using border-collapse the outer border was removed and obviously there was nothing to round.